# Mixing MyISAM and InnoDB engines for database design

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

One of my friends, who is a DBA, commented that mixing MyISAM and InnoDB is fairly common  among the DBA community, while designing schema in MySQL.

My question is, if this is true, then how good it is? Does it have any effect in the maintainability, scalability etc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are generally very few good reasons remaining to use MyISAM. Newer versions of MySQL (5.5+) have extended InnoDB to support all the features that were previously only available on MyISAM (such as fulltext and geospatial indexing), and InnoDB performance is usually considerably better than MyISAM when configured properly.

Unless you are working with an older version of MySQL, or if you have a *very* good reason for doing so, I'd recommend just using InnoDB throughout any new database design.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, this is one of the terrible things about MySQL: that it makes you choose between speed and full-text indices (MyISAM) and referential integrity and transactions (InnoDB). If you can, I highly recommend switching to PostgreSQL: in addition to a number of other advantages, you get speed, full-text indices, transactions, and referential integrity in one storage engine. (I no longer use MySQL for new projects at all.)

If you must stick with MySQL, I recommend using InnoDB on all tables unless you have a particular reason not to.

Comment: Just a bit out of the topic, do you have a benchmark stat which clearly states PostgreSQL is faster than MySQL? That'll be helpful for me.

Comment: I didn't actually say it was. However, since you asked, benchmarks seem to indicate that it's faster than InnoDB (and more capable than MyISAM). I can't seem to find actual numbers right now, but check out http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL . Also note that PostgreSQL does backwards index scans, while MySQL does not.

Comment: Some of you're describing is actually no longer true -- with MySQL 5.5+, InnoDB is generally faster all-around than MyISAM, and supports full-text indexes.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Does it support backwards index scans and transactional DDL yet?

Answer (score 2):

On a practical note.

I have done it a number of times. Notably on one system where queries were locking a whole table as myisam and we converted a number of the critical tables to innodb so they locked at the row level. This removed some bottlenecks from the process and i was with the company for another 18 months after this change with no problems from that solution.  The application being supported made fairly intensive use of the database as well so any inadequacies tended to come to light quite quickly.